# How to fix the top navigation bar with class navbar navbar-inverse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am beginner to use bootstrap and tried many solution for fixing top of navigation bar but not fruitful. I want to use the drop down menu in this navigation bar also.

Please see at below code and help me out to fix the top navigation bar using bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#myNavbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>


                        <?php
                        if ( $_SESSION['State'] == 'Authenticated'){
                        ?>



                        <li>
                            <a href='#'><?php echo $_SESSION['UserName']; ?></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href='#'>Active</a>
                        </li>

                        <?php    

                        }else{

                        ?>

                        <li>
                            <a href='register.php'>Register/Login</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="mydomain">Admin Login</a>
                        </li>

                        <?php  
                            }
                        ?>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also if possible please update any addition required in above code so that to  fix the top navigation bar.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? Do you mean `positioned:fixed`? Are you actually using Bootstrap 4? The navbar code you posted looks like Bootstrap 3.

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap but don't know about bootstrap-3 or 4

Comment: fix mean when i scroll down then  my navigation header should remain there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top">
…
</nav>
```

This is the default value of bootstrap `fixed-top` :

```
.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

For more details, please have a quick look: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: but will the navbar-inverse remain there

Comment: but i need this `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">`

Comment: `navbar-inverse` does not exist my friend… anymore I guess

Comment: Thanks i used your css hint and updated my css class `navbar-inverse`